# Conditional IF statement syntax in BC

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash function that is the inversion of the function in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687565/1277576.

The purpose is to obtain the decimal representation of a number from its binary representation in two's complement.

```
dec() {
  n=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
  x=$(echo "ibase=2; $1" | bc)
  echo "if ($x<2^($n-1)) $x else -$((~$x))-1" | bc
}
```

My issue is that it works only for negative binary integers *(that is, when the most significant bit is equal to 1)*, while if fails for positive ones *(that is, when the most significant bit is equal to 0)*:

```
$ dec 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
-1
$ dec 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-9223372036854775808
$ dec 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

It seems that the line `echo "if ($x<2^($n-1)) $x else -$((~$x))-1" | bc` contains a syntax error, but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: enable debug mode (`set -xv`) and review the output; you should find the `echo` is not generating what you think it is

Comment: In the failing example, echo generates echo 'if (1<2^(64-1)) 1 else --2-1'. I guess that the issue could be the double minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
$ dec() {
  printf 'n=%d; ibase=2; v=%s; v-2^n*(v/2^(n-1))\n' "$(getconf LONG_BIT)" "$1"| bc
}
$ dec 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
-1
$ dec 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
dec() {
  n=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
  x=$(echo "ibase=2; $1" | bc)
  echo "if ($x<2^($n-1)) $x else -($((~$x))+1)" | bc
}
```

The problem was the double minus sign, as pointed in the comment [Conditional IF statement syntax in BC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691181/conditional-if-statement-syntax-in-bc?noredirect=1#comment128400631_72691181).